# MS sql 2008 r2 - evaluate an expression which is in a variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, expression

I am using Ms sql server 2008 and I am store expessions in an nvarchar variable. I would like evaulate them as a normal expression.

Here is my example from the management studio:

```
DECLARE @exp nvarchar (50)
SET @exp ='(1&1)|1'
PRINT (1&0)|1
PRINT @exp
```

The expected result of the last line is 1.

I found this link on the technet site. ([EvaluateAsExpression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variable.evaluateasexpression%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))

It uses some C# code which I don't know how to implement in the management studio.
Or do you have other solution?

Thank, Tamas!

Comment: I don't think you can evaluate strings as expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXEC` can evaluate expressions, see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14218):

```
DECLARE @exp nvarchar (50)
SET @exp = N'1+2+3+4+5';
exec (N'SELECT ' + @exp);
```

I would advise against such though. If you want to use a *safe* expression evaluator, build one in CLR and integrate it as a SQLCLR function, see [How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Capture value in variable:

```
DECLARE @exp nvarchar (50)
SET @exp = N'1+2+3+4+5';

declare @result int;
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'set @result = (' + @exp + ');';
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result int output', @result output;

select @result;
```

the usual caution has to be in place whenever executing dynamic SQL, this is a possible SQL injection attack vector so the input must be absolutely trusted. One more reason why a custom built parser in C# would be better/safer.

Comment: This is almost good. Can you put somehow the result into a variable so the can continue to work with it? I tried this but its not ok `declare @result int
set @result=exec (N'SELECT ' + @exp)`

Comment: use `sp_executesql`. The real problem is the *type* of the variable. If the expression is arbitrary, you do not know what will the output be. See update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a dynamic query and executing it:

```
DECLARE @exp nvarchar (50)

SET @exp ='(1&1)|1'
PRINT (1&0)|1

SET @exp = 'PRINT ' + @exp
EXEC sp_executesql @exp
```

This will actually create a new PRINT statement with the contents of `@exp` variable and execute it.